# How to change the drag animation while dragging a row in antd?

Tags: reactjs, antd, react-dnd

I am using Ant Design's draggable table in a project. I am using the source code that is available for the example on their website. It works fine with drag and drop functionality but I want to change the animation when I am dragging a row. Right now it shows the snapshot of the row selected while dragging it around.

I went through the React-DnD documentation, since it is what is being used by antd. In it, there is a mention of DragPreviewImage. Now I assume it would be what is required but since I am very new to it, I am having a hard time in discovering how to fit what they say into the simple example given on the antd's website.

Following is the link to the sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/embed/dazzling-sammet-e41lf

I would like anyone's help to show me how we can change the drag animation in this source code. I will be very thankful.